# I am trying to push my code to the company's repository

Tags: tortoisehg

I am using tortoise client against a remote repository.  I can pull and merge, but when I try to push my changes I get this error:

```
abort: push creates new remote head fd3cfa09ec66!
hint: did you forget to merge? use push -f to force
```

[image]

Comment: Check and show `hg heads` + `hg incoming`

Comment: @Lazy - is there a way to do that from TortoiseHG?

Comment: I've just answered .. have look

Comment: marking as "answer" you really help :)

Answer (score 2):

it seems that something was pushed from another part. try to "pull" and "merge" their changes, then "push" your code